# CSS Clip Path - Invalid Property Value

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a complex `clip-path` from a logo in CSS and the console is giving me a `Invalid Property Value` I have calculated the X & Y axis based on a width and height of `508px x 190px`

[image: This is the logo I am working from]

This is the logo I am working from

And this is the css:

```
    .container {
        width:  508px;
        height: 190px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoBAMAAAB+0KVeAAAAHlBMVEUAAABkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGSH0mEbAAAACnRSTlMAzDPDPPPYnGMw2CgMzQAAAChJREFUKM9jgAPOAgZMwGIwKkhXQSUY0BCCMxkEYUAsEM4cjI4fwYIAf2QMNbUsZjcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
        background-size: 10px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }


    .logo-clip {
        width:  100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: purple;
        clip-path: 
            polygon(
                0 0,
                12% 0,
                12% 75%,
                26% 75%,
                26% 48%,
                37% 48%,
                37% 29%,
                26% 29%
                26% 0,
                37% 0,
                57% 69%,
                57% 0,
                69% 0,
                69% 34%,
                82% 0,
                98% 0,
                78% 48%,
                100% 100%,
                84% 100%,
                69% 63%,
                69% 100%,
                51% 100%,
                37% 49%,
                37% 100%,
                0 100%,
                0 0
            );
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo-clip"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong I calculated 26 points to work from and I have 26 X/Y pairs in the polygon ‍♂️

Comment: Could you provide your html structure ?

Comment: @CharlesLavalard I have added the structure it is very simple HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `26% 29%`

Comment: What an idiot I have been chasing that for hours, thanks so much!

Comment: :D no problem. Fancy marking it as the correct answer? ;)

Comment: nice one bro, thanks! (I could do with the points haha)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `,` after `26% 29%` in  the clip-path.

```css
.container {
        width:  508px;
        height: 190px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoBAMAAAB+0KVeAAAAHlBMVEUAAABkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGSH0mEbAAAACnRSTlMAzDPDPPPYnGMw2CgMzQAAAChJREFUKM9jgAPOAgZMwGIwKkhXQSUY0BCCMxkEYUAsEM4cjI4fwYIAf2QMNbUsZjcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
        background-size: 10px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }


    .logo-clip {
        width:  100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: purple;
        clip-path: 
            polygon(
                0 0,
                12% 0,
                12% 75%,
                26% 75%,
                26% 48%,
                37% 48%,
                37% 29%,
                26% 29%,
                26% 0,
                37% 0,
                57% 69%,
                57% 0,
                69% 0,
                69% 34%,
                82% 0,
                98% 0,
                78% 48%,
                100% 100%,
                84% 100%,
                69% 63%,
                69% 100%,
                51% 100%,
                37% 49%,
                37% 100%,
                0 100%,
                0 0
            );
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo-clip"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is right just the `color` needs to be `rgb(6, 173, 173)` and there is a syntax mistake of a `,` after `26% 29%`.

```
  .logo-clip {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(6, 173, 173);
  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    12% 0,
    12% 75%,
    26% 75%,
    26% 48%,
    37% 48%,
    37% 29%,
    26% 29%,
    26% 0,
    37% 0,
    57% 69%,
    57% 0,
    69% 0,
    69% 34%,
    82% 0,
    98% 0,
    78% 48%,
    100% 100%,
    84% 100%,
    69% 63%,
    69% 100%,
    51% 100%,
    37% 49%,
    37% 100%,
    0 100%,
    0 0
  );
}
```